# Gradle Direct File Reference From Git Repo

Tags: gradle, lint

I'm trying to use Gradle to include non-Java source from a separate git repository into certain build steps, and the dependent code needs to be able to reference the source file directly. The use case is this: We are attempting to modularize linting configurations (in this case, ESLint), such that common configs are extracted to our style guide repo and imported into all relevant repos. Note that we don't want to use NPM package management for this purpose because we will also ultimately use this for other languages such as Java and would like to use the same system across projects. Imagine the following setup:

```
| ProjectA (github.com/org/ProjectA)
|---- build.gradle
|---- settings.gradle
|---- .eslintrc.js
|---- src/
|----|---- (a bunch of js files)
| ProjectB (github.com/org/ProjectB)
|---- build.gradle
|---- settings.gradle
|---- .eslintrc.js
|---- src/
|----|---- (a bunch of js files)
| ProjectC (github.com/org/ProjectC)
|---- build.gradle
|---- settings.gradle
|---- dir_containing_config/
|----|---- base_eslintrc.js
```

`.eslintrc.js` in project A and project B want to extend `dir_containing_config/base_eslintrc.js` in project C.

I'm no Gradle expert, but I was looking into it and found Source Dependencies to be a good possibility, but I'm not finding anything about how to directly access the directory containing the *raw source* from the build script (as opposed to the jar, which I have been able to accessing using the configuration that depends on the SourceDep). The plan I have in mind so far is, once I'm able to access that dir from the build script, have a task copy/link all of that dir's contents to a more accessible dir that doesn't have the crazy generated path that would be difficult or impossible to reference from `.eslintrc.js`.

Do you know how I can accomplish what I want to do? I'm open to entirely new approaches if the one I'm taking is not effective or efficient for this purpose.

Thanks!